# how to install Windows Bootloader to MBR?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot, grub, bootloader

previously i had dual boot sytem with windows 7 and ubuntu.
i tried removing ubuntu by formatting my system to factory condition using in-built recovery as i dint have external drive for that.
but after the formatting was complete, i can not boot into 7 . it shoes error grub rescue.!!!
discussed the problem on ubuntu forum. they asked me to use this forum.
so help me out how can boot back into my windows 7.
PS: i dont have external recovery disk . reeovery is in built on sony vaio laptop i am using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to go back to Windows 8, how? I deleted Ubuntu 16.04 and the Windows bootloader doesn't work](http://superuser.com/questions/1150154/i-want-to-go-back-to-windows-8-how-i-deleted-ubuntu-16-04-and-the-windows-boot)

Answer (score 1):

## How to Manually Repair Windows 7 Boot Loader Problems

follow few steps

step 1:
The first thing you’ll need to do is boot off the install disc, and then click through until you see the “Repair your computer” link in the lower left-hand corner.[image]

Step 2 :You’ll need to choose the correct installation of Windows and then click the Next button.[image]

Step 3 :And then you’ll get to the System Recovery Options screen, where you can get to the Command Prompt.

[image]

## Repairing the Master Boot Record

If you want to restore the master boot record, you can simply type in the following command:

> bootrec /fixmbr

You can also write a new boot sector onto the system partition with this command (which is often more useful):

> bootrec /fixboot

And of course, if you just use bootrec /? you’ll be able to see all the options.[image]

## Using the Automated Startup Repair

Of course, all this command-line stuff is probably not necessary in most cases. You can usually just use the Startup Repair option from the Recovery menu…
[image]

It’ll check for problems and probably fix them. If not, then you can always use the command prompt.Have you ever needed to restore your boot loader to get Windows working again?

[image]

Comment: If you copy the whole article (including images and the finishing sentence) from another site, you should at least link the [original source](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/32523/how-to-manually-repair-windows-7-boot-loader-problems/) I think.

Comment: I know brother whole article is copied from howtogeek my motive is only give solution .Copying from a single source is called plagiarism, copying from multiple source is called research.

Comment: thanks fo your suggestions. but i want to know one more thing.
if i boot my system using a downloaded cracked windows CD, then also my original windows will remain there or will that be ovveridden by the downloaded windows CD i have used for booting.?

Comment: If you manually install the boot loader its make changes only in MBR if you select the option "system restore" thus its make changes, its depend on the windows which used to repair

Answer (score 0):

In order to repair Windows Bootloader, you'll need an external recovery disk, as you need to boot on a windows system and your grub is broken (you deleted its files).

If you don't have one, you can still make one. You just need to download a Windows 7 ISO and burn it. And if you don't have a DVD to burn it, you can put it on a bootable USB, with [this Microsoft tool](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool).
Well, you still need an other computer for that.

In your situation, an automatic repair should bring your bootloader back. If it doesn't, you can still try opening a console in the repair/install DVD environment and run `Bootrec.exe/FixBoot`.

Comment: thanks fo your suggestions. but i want to know one more thing. if i boot my system using a downloaded cracked windows CD, then also my original windows will remain there or will that be ovveridden by the downloaded windows CD i have used for booting.?

Comment: @ANTRIX repairing boot sector with a Windows installation DVD cracked or not, should not affect your Windows installation at all, only the bootloader. However, you do not neeed a cracked copy to do this, any Windows 7 installation DVD should be ok.

Answer (score -2):

See [I want to go back to Windows 8, how? I deleted Ubuntu 16.04 and the Windows bootloader doesn't work](https://superuser.com/questions/1150154/i-want-to-go-back-to-windows-8-how-i-deleted-ubuntu-16-04-and-the-windows-boot/1150161#1150161)

TLDR; Reinstall Ubuntu, don't overwrite your windows partition. This should put your computer back into dual-booting order then follow [How to make Windows bootloader the default?](https://superuser.com/questions/11489/how-to-make-windows-bootloader-the-default?rq=1) after you boot back into Windows 7. EasyBCD can overwrite the bootloader your computer uses back with Window's MBR. From that point you should be free to uninstall Ubuntu by deleting it's partition through Windows if you like.

~No worries we've all been there~ (no repair disk required)

Comment: This is just an answer that links to existing answers.  You didn't even include the relevant information into your answer.  It also seems to duplicate information that already exists in an answer to this question.  You linked to another answer, which is also a link only answer, which points to this [question](http://superuser.com/questions/11489/how-to-make-windows-bootloader-the-default?rq=1) the correct course of action is to flag this question as a duplicate of that question if you beleive one of your existing (answers) actually answers this question

Comment: @Ramhound well I don't exactly use flags, but I'd be happy to flag it as a duplicate.

Comment: You should do that or edit your answer to include the relevant information.  If all you are going to do is provide a link, you might as well flag it as a duplicate, because thats all that will happen is a link to the duplicate will be created.

Comment: @Ramhound No worries...I've marked it as duplicate. What relevant information should I throw in here? Clearly he's installed and dual-booted ubuntu before, he knows that process, I've specifically mentioned not to overwrite the windows 7 partition. Which should put his computer back into booting order. After that, it's a matter of booting into windows and following that post.

Comment: If I tell you want to include in your answer.  I might as well write my own answer and submit it.  I indicate your answer should be more then just a link, and you should cite and quote the information from your links, and you currently have duplicate information which exists in existing answers to this question in your answer

Comment: @Ramhound well I'm not sure my edited answer meets your standards, but we'll see if the answer doesn't get marked as duplicate anyway.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49489/discussion-between-theunknowngeek-and-ramhound).