# I want to go back to Windows 8, how? I deleted Ubuntu 16.04 and the Windows bootloader doesn't work

Tags: windows-8, boot, bootloader

I know my questions looks similar to others, but they have not been answered as to solve my problem. I'm from Mexico. I got an ASUS S451L. I got the computer with windows 8 then I upgraded it with windows 10. A week ago I got a virus and lost all my data, so I decided to install Ubuntu 16.04, because I read good reviews about it. I was very excited, but after I installed. I tried to get my favorites videogames (LoL;GuildofWars2) running but they wouldn't work on Linux. Yes, I installed Wine and play on Linux. I had to installed Ubuntu again because after trying to install GW2, it crashed.

I got tired and decided to go back to windows. Unfortunately, I never backed up windows; I was afraid I deleted forever, so people told me to buy a new license or get it pirate. But somehow , reading forum, I got to know if I still had the ISO. the only problem was that I couldn't boot it. GRUB would get on the way. Anyways, I repaired the boot loader using that Ubuntu application Boot-repair. I got to the command thing where I can type bootrec /Fixboot or /Fixmbr. It told me that the processes were succesful. But it was still booting GRUB. I prioritize Windows Boot manager (yes , it gave me theoption) but it wouldn't boot it. I uninstalled UBUNTU hoping it would stop booting GRUB, but it was still booting (in a blackscreen with inframes thing). In conclusion, it is not booting windows and evennthough I got a Windows 8.1 PRO iso, it sends me an error of compatibility:

"The computer started using Windows Installation media. Remove the installation media and restart your computer so that Windows starts normally. Then, insert the installation media and restart the upgrade. [DO not select !custom [advanced] to perform an upgrade. !custom advance installs a new copy of Windows and deletes your programs and settings/" I read something that said this happened because it read the booter my computer has as default.
I have my key license. I just need to boot Windows 8 so I can install it. Is it possible? What could I do? Am I doomed? Will Yuri ever marry Victor? HELP ME !!

Greetings !

P.S. sorry for the long post. 
P.S.2 I don't know anything about programming or those things in case you didn't notice.
P.S.3 I tried the DISKPART thing but it didn't do anything when I typed the coomand "ren bcd bcd.bak".

Comment: Boot on Ubuntu and erase your entire hard drive by writing `sudo shred -n 1 -v /dev/sda` in a terminal. Make sure you have backups as this will completely nuke your HDD. Once that's done you can reboot on your Windows disc.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure, your system uses MBR? May be it's GPT?

In Ubuntu as SU check following path: `/boot/efi`(something like `sudo ls /boot/efi/`), if it's non-empty, you are, probably, using EFI bootloader.

**Way 1**:
 Check out sizes of `/boot/efi/EFI/BOOT/BOOTx64.efi` and `/boot/efi/EFI/grub/grubx64.efi` (don't sure about directory, it can be `ubuntu`, or just `linux`), if they match -- your system uses fallback bootloader, which is set to GRUB.

From same `/boot/efi/EFI` folder copy `Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` to `BOOT/bootx64.efi` replacing it (better make a backup first).

Now your system should boot with Windows bootloader.

**Way 2**:
As `su` run `efibootmgr`, if it's not found -- you, probably, are not using EFI.
Elsewise it will print current bootloader, boot order and your registered EFI bootloaders. Check out `man efibootmgr` to set up your bootorder in preferred way.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Pavlus . I don't know much about computer. I didn't understand well "In Ubuntu as SU", but I types "su" in the terminal and it is asking me for a password. I don't know what password is asking me to write S:
I don't know what MBR or GPT is, but when I did the "fixmbr" thing in the command (blackscreen) it says that the fix was successful. This could mean that my system uses MBR?

Comment: No, it doesn't mean anything. If you don't know your Super User password -- use a prefix `sudo ` before a command needed to be executed as Super User, it will ask you your _current user's_ password (`su` starts a shell with admin privileges, where you can type commands, but `sudo` executes single command as admin and asks current user password instead of admin password).

Answer (score -1):

If you can, reinstall ubuntu, don't overwrite the entire disk, (if your windows 8 partition is still there you'll be ok) then take the steps to make Windows 8 your default bootloader (see [How to make Windows bootloader the default?](https://superuser.com/questions/11489/how-to-make-windows-bootloader-the-default?rq=1))

Then you can remove Ubuntu's partition if you'd like.

Comment: EasyBCD is a fairly uncomplicated way of fixing the issue if you manage to get your setup for dual-booting back up again, you should be able to get right back into Windows and fix your setup there. You can if you'd like keep dual-booting with the Windows bootloader where Linux is secondary.

If you can't log back into Windows with your dual-booting setup, you may need to look up more in-depth ways to restore the master boot record while you're in Ubuntu (like in the other post)