# How to use Windows 10 graphical bootloader instead of grub?

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, bootloader, manjaro, dualboot

First of all I own a Lenovo with a Core2Duo CPU. It had Windows 7 preinstalled in it and later I installed Windows 10.

Whenever I boot, I come across a Windows 10 graphical bootloader.

Now I want to install Manjaro Linux doing triple boot or I will delete windows 7 partition and install Manjaro there.

I've seen youtube videos dual booting Windows 10 and Manjaro. When they boot there appear a ugly GRUB bootloader.

All I want is that I want to install Manjaro and still be asked for booting by Windows 10 graphical bootloader and not GRUB.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Lots of answers to this question already. https://superuser.com/questions/11489/how-to-make-windows-bootloader-the-default?noredirect=1&lq=1 
 https://superuser.com/questions/1247912/how-to-make-windows-10-bootloader-as-default-bootloader

Comment: Basic idea is to add a grub entry in windows bootloader ; Will suggest you to add this manually without using EasyBCD (third-party software and buggy) ; will write as answer if you choose not to otherwise there are lot of answers already ; so let me know.

Comment: Ok.Write about how to do it manually and thanks to you 

Comment: I would like to tell you that I have two hard disks in my machine and **windows 10** and **manjaro** are on hard disk zero and **windows7** is on hard disk one

Comment: I have installed manjaro and at the time of boot grub bootloader appears with Linux manjaro and windows 10 booting option i want windows graphical boot manager

Comment: @aditya-gadekar try it and feel free to accept it if it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic idea - copy the boot record of our linux distro partition to Windows , and using BCDEdit to create a new entry in the BCD store that will point to that file. This way Windows will display a menu at boot time that will give you a choice between Windows and Linux distro.

Boot into Linux
First, create a directory to save boot record. Open a terminal and enter the following:

```
sudo su

mkdir /mnt/share
```

Write the first 512 bytes of our linux disro partition(sdxy) to a file

```
dd if=/dev/sdx of=/mnt/share/linux.bin bs=512 count=1
```

copy the linux.bin file located in /mnt/share/ to any other desired location.(will need it after booting into windows)

Boot into windows
open the volume where you copied the linux.bin file.

```
Copy that file to the root of the Windows volume (e.g., C:).
```

use BCDEdit to add an entry to Windows BCD store. Administrative privileges are required to use BCDEdit, so use Win+r, type cmd, and then press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER. start by creating an entry for our Linux distribution. Note here that you are free to choose another entry name if desired:

```
bcdedit /create /d “Linux” /application bootsector
```

BCDEdit will return an alphanumeric identifier for this entry that I will refer to as {ID} in the remaining steps. You’ll need to replace {ID} by the actual returned identifier.Next, specify which partition hosts a copy of the linux.bin file:

```
bcdedit /set {ID} device partition=c:
```

The path to our linux.bin file:

```
bcdedit /set {ID}  path \linux.bin
```

An entry to the displayed menu at boot time:

```
bcdedit /displayorder {ID} /addlast
```

and finally, let’s specify how long the menu choices will be displayed:

```
bcdedit /timeout 30
```

On a final note, if at any time you want to eliminate the Linux menu option simply delete the BCD store entry you created using the following command:

```
bcdedit /delete {ID}
```

Now
[Make windows bootloader the default](https://superuser.com/q/949219/777184)

```
bootsect /nt60 C: /force /mbr
```

That’s it! Now reboot and you will be presented with menu where you can choose to boot to Windows or Linux.

Comment: It's my pleasure that you took out time and wrote this much big answer **but** i have a problem, i deletes Linux partition where manjaro was installed and now I am stucked into **grub boot rescue**  and unfortunately I don't have windows 10 bootable media to repair my system **can you plz help me with that?**

Comment: @AdityaGadekar can by directly boot into win 7 if you disconnect the other drive or change the boot order

Comment: Ok I'll try it but what's later?

Comment: @AdityaGadekar create a windows bootable USB > repair > command prompt ;then follow https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/927392/use-bootrec-exe-in-the-windows-re-to-troubleshoot-startup-issues to restore windows 10 bootloader and then this https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/repair-the-boot-menu-on-a-dual-boot-pc to add win 7 boot to win 10 bootloader

Comment: @AdityaGadekar and when trying to reinstall linux again make sure to install grub bootloader to the root partition instead of whole disk and after installation is finished make the copy of boot record (refer to the answer for detailed steps)from live USB only without rebooting into newly installed distro

Comment: i have innumerable boubts about dual boot can you give me your insta id or you can dm me on @_x__a_d_i_t_y_a__x_

Comment: @AdityaGadekar feel free to ask new questions but make sure question are unique, specific and not duplicate

Comment: id plz.........

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if this will work, but I did read about a tool called EasyBCD (https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) that may help you out. This article kinda explains it: https://www.groovypost.com/howto/dual-boot-windows-10-linux/ . This is their Docs: https://neosmart.net/wiki/easybcd/basics/adding-entries/ .

Disclaimer: I personally have never used this tool, so use at your own risk.

If your system supports UEFI and looks are the problem, (I do agree, grub is not ideal looks-wise...) I'm currently Multibooting Windows 10 and Ubuntu and using reFIND with a custom theme that I tweaked that looks decent enough for me. (https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/themes.html)